# Magento Fatal error: Interface 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface'

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento install moved onto a new server all files present but in the admin when navigating to a number of areas including manage products, configuration, manage attributes I get the below error.

> Fatal error: Interface 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface' not found in 
>   /home/websitepath/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Renderer/Element.php 
>   on line 35

I have checked and the file is present the same as on other live install.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface` is referenced from `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Renderer/Interface.php` My guess would be that either the filepath is wrong or the folder has not been copied correctly from the previous installation.

Comment: yes you are correct, I just checked and the /Renderer folder was missing, uploaded and works. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Great - probably worth checking over the entire structure to ensure all files are in place.  Please feel free to accept this as the answer.